# ggplot geom_point make the points bigger when using aes

Tags: ggplot2, geom-point

In ggplot I want to make the `geom_point`s bigger overall when they are in an aes. For example:

```
ggplot(diamonds %>% head(30)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = cut, y=color, size=carat))
```

Gives exactly the same plot as

```
ggplot(diamonds %>% head(30)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = cut, y=color, size=10*carat))
```

[image: size of points don't change with 10*]

You can do this outside the aes, but it doesn't work within

```
ggplot(diamonds %>% head(30)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = cut, y=color), size=10))
```

Comment: Whenever you pass something inside `aes()`, it gets mapped to a scale, which typically rescales it to some output range, i.e. `c(1, 6)` for `scale_size_continuous()`. You can set that size larger in the scale if you want. For a scale, it doesn't matter that the input range is [0-100] or [-1e6, 1e6], the output will be according to the output range.

Comment: ah, lovely, adding ` + scale_size(range = c(0, 40))` solved this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @teunbrand comment:

```
ggplot(diamonds %>% head(30)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = cut, y=color, size=carat)) +
  scale_size(range = c(0, 40))
```

[image: larger sized aes points]